# Documentation error "qdoc can't run; no project set in qdocconf file"

Tags: qt, documentation

I am trying to generate documentation for my code using QDoc. `qtdoc` command is already in my environment variable path. But when I try to run the command in the root directory of the project *(qdocconf file also resides in project root)*,

```
qdoc projectname.qdocconf
```

I get the following error

**qt.qdoc: "qdoc can't run; no project set in qdocconf file"**

Here is my `projectname.qdocconf` file.

```
headers.fileextensions  = "*.h *.hpp"
sources.fileextensions  = "*.cpp *.qml *.qdoc"

outputdir   = Documentation/Code
headerdirs  += Code
sourcedirs  +=  . \
                Code
exampledirs = .
imagedirs   += ./Images/icons \
                ./Images/logos
```

I have commented on my class functions as described in the documentation using the format

```
/*!
 * \fn void inlineFunction()
 *
 * Some info here...
 */
```

Can you point me what am I doing wrong?

Also, can I create the documentation using QtCreator instead of running the command in terminal?

Answer (score 3):

Well somehow I figured out that you need to add the following line in your **.qdocconf** file

```
project = YourProjectName
```

which is not present in the minimum qdocconf file presented in https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoc-minimum-qdocconf.html. Even though the above issue was resolved, a lot of other issues were encountered such as:

1. While compiling, `qt.qdoc: No include paths passed to qdoc; guessing reasonable include paths`. For this you have to manually include all the source paths. Read: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-67289
2. Some comment tags, e.g. \return, \param, present in QtCreator are not recognized by QDoc

**Option 2**

Alternatively, look for [Doxygen](https://www.doxygen.nl/index.html) which is much easier to use and generate documents with a simple to use GUI. It also recognizes all the comment tags in QtCreator.

**Update:**

Doxygen plugins for Qt Creator doesn't work anymore as the support has expired. Use Doxygen GUI directly.